# Search DateTime using Entity Framework Core with TempData

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> I need to search between two dates (From Date, To Date) using entity framework core with TempData, but, until now i phase some problems.

Here is the code for model

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayName("Activity Log Date Time")]
    public DateTime ActivityLogDateTime { get; set; }
```

and the controller code this one

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Index")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, string operation, string userName, string pageName, string number)
    {
        //Viewbag information for view
        ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate;
        ViewBag.toDate = toDate;
        ViewBag.operation = operation;
        ViewBag.userName = userName;
        ViewBag.pageName = pageName;

        //To store search data
        TempData["fromDate"] = fromDate;
        TempData["toDate"] = toDate;
        TempData["operation"] = operation;
        TempData["userName"] = userName;
        TempData["pageName"] = pageName;

        //Check if number == null then put default value 10
        if (number == null)
        {
            number = "10";
        }


        //Record Activity Logs
        activity.PageId = 1;
        var name = await db.Pages.FindAsync(activity.PageId);
        activity.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        activity.Operation = "Search";
        activity.Description = "Username: (" + User.Identity.Name + ") search in page number " + activity.PageId.ToString() + " (" + name.PageName + ")";
        activity.TechnicalDescription = "Username = " + User.Identity.Name + ", PageId = " + activity.PageId.ToString() + ", fromDate = " + fromDate
            + ", toDate = " + toDate + ", operation = " + operation + ", username = " + userName + ", pagename = " + pageName;
        activity.ActivityLogDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        //End Record Activity Logs

        db.ActivityLogs.Add(activity);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();


        if (fromDate.Year.ToString().Equals("1") && toDate.Year.ToString().Equals("1") && operation == null && userName == null && pageName == null) 
        {
            return View(await db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, 10));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(await db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime)
            .Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate && string.IsNullOrEmpty(operation) ? true : x.Operation.Contains(operation)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) ? true : x.Username.Contains(userName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName) ? true : x.Pages.PageName.Contains(pageName))
            .ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, int.Parse(number)));
        }

    }

public FileResult ExportExcel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] { new DataColumn("Activity Logs Id"),
                                        new DataColumn("Date and Time"),
                                        new DataColumn("Username"),
                                        new DataColumn("Operation"),
                                        new DataColumn("Description"),
                                        new DataColumn("Technical Description"),
                                        new DataColumn("PageName")});

        var report = new List<ActivityLogs>();

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["fromDate"].ToString()).Year.ToString().Equals("1") && Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["toDate"]).Year.ToString().Equals("1") 
            && TempData["operation"].ToString() == null && TempData["userName"].ToString() == null && TempData["pageName"].ToString() == null)
        {
            report = db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            report = db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime)
            .Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["fromDate"].ToString()) && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["toDate"].ToString())
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["operation"].ToString()) ? true : x.Operation.Contains(TempData["operation"].ToString())
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["userName"].ToString()) ? true : x.Username.Contains(TempData["userName"].ToString()) 
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["pageName"].ToString()) ? true : x.Pages.PageName.Contains(TempData["pageName"].ToString())).ToList();
        }


        foreach (var item in report)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.ActivityLogId, item.ActivityLogDateTime, item.Username, item.Operation, item.Description, item.TechnicalDescription,
                item.Pages.PageName);
        }

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "ActivityLogs " + DateTime.Now +".xlsx");
            }
        }

    }
```

**When I need to export the excel files i found this error:**

> **NullReferenceException:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> **InvalidOperationException:** An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.

**My code work like this:**

1. User search put the search criteria (from date, to date, ...)
2. Then user click search button
3. After that they can export the search data that he search, because I saved search data in TempData[] dictionary and passed this TempData[] dictionary to ExportExcel FileResult.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Are you sure that this error is because of `TempData`?

Comment: @mmushtaq , I dubug the program step by step and I am sure that this error come from the TempData, because the search part work fine and it is the same code for export excel file

Comment: `ToString()`  throws `Null Reference Exception` if it finds `null`, so `TempData["key"].ToString() == null` also can  cause `Null Reference` error. First check for null like `TempData["operation"] != null` and then apply `ToString()` conversion..

Comment: @mmushtaq, DateTime can't be null, it come with default value 01/01/0001 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,

**First of all:**

> When you need to read the TempData in Asp.Net Core 3.0 you should read like this `TempData["YourDictionaryParameter"] as string` not like this `TempData["YourDictionaryParameter"].toString()`

Now let's see the code that i used to export,

1. I created this method to handle the search

   ```
   private List<ActivityLogs> GetSearchResult()
   {
       DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["fromDate"].ToString());
       DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["toDate"].ToString());
       string operation = TempData["operation"] as string;
       string userName = TempData["userName"] as string;
       string pageName = TempData["pageName"] as string;
       TempData.Keep();

       if (fromDate == default(DateTime) && toDate == default(DateTime))
       {
           if (operation == null && userName == null && pageName == null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).ToList();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (operation != null && userName == null && pageName == null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Operation.Contains(operation)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation == null && userName != null && pageName == null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Username.Contains(userName)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation == null & userName == null && pageName != null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Pages.PageName.Contains(userName)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation != null && userName != null && pageName == null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Username.Contains(operation) && x.Username.Contains(userName)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation != null && userName == null && pageName != null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Operation.Contains(operation) && x.Pages.PageName.Contains(pageName)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation == null && userName != null && pageName != null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Username.Contains(userName) && x.Pages.PageName.Contains(pageName)).ToList();
           }
           else if (operation != null && userName != null && pageName != null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate
               && x.Operation.Contains(operation) && x.Username.Contains(userName) && x.Pages.PageName.Contains(pageName)).ToList();
           }
           else if(operation == null && userName == null && pageName == null)
           {
               return db.ActivityLogs.Include(x => x.Pages).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).Where(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime >= fromDate && x.ActivityLogDateTime <= toDate).ToList();
           }

       }

       return db.ActivityLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityLogDateTime).ToList();
   }
   ```
2. After I create the search method I applied it to export method

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> ExportPDF()
   {
       var activityLogs = await new List<ActivityLogs>().ToListAsync();

       activityLogs = GetSearchResult();

       var report = new ViewAsPdf("ActivityLogsReport", activityLogs)
       {
           PageMargins = { Left = 20, Bottom = 10, Right = 20, Top = 10 },
           FileName = "ActivityLogs " + DateTime.Now + ".pdf",
           PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
           PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
           //CustomSwitches = "--page-offset 0 --footer-center [page] --footer-font-size 12"
           CustomSwitches = "--footer-center \"  Created Date: " +
                       DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "  Page: [page]/[toPage]\"" +
                       " --footer-line --footer-font-size \"12\" --footer-spacing 1 --footer-font-name \"Segoe UI\""
       };
       return report;
   }
   ```

After that you will find that export to excel work fine and return what user search correctly.